# I just can't get openSSL Support enabled

Tags: php, openssl

I am on php 8.1.2, wampserver 3.2.7 64bit, and apache 2.4.35

The apache php.ini (D:\Programmes\Wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.35\bin\php.ini) has both of these lines uncommented

```
extension_dir = "D:/Programmes/Wamp/bin/php/php8.1.2/ext/"

extension=openssl
```

The php php.ini (D:\Programmes\Wamp\bin\php\php8.1.2\php.ini) also has both of these lines uncommented

D:\Programmes\Wamp\bin\php\php8.1.2\ext\php_openssl.dll does exist

And I did restart Apache (and all of wamp services)

From what I found on internet, usually this is enough to get things to work. But for me it doesn't, when I look on phpinfo, the line "openSLL Support" still shows "disabled (install ext/openssl)".

I also checked on that same phpinfo what is the path to php.ini, and it is correctly D:\Programmes\Wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.35\bin\php.ini

Any idea on what is going wrong ? Thanks !

Edit: In my php_error.log I have these 4 lines :

```
[12-Oct-2022 16:23:38 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'curl' (tried: D:/Programmes/Wamp/bin/php/php8.1.2/ext/curl (Le module spécifié est introuvable), D:/Programmes/Wamp/bin/php/php8.1.2/ext/php_curl.dll (La procédure spécifiée est introuvable)) in Unknown on line 0
[12-Oct-2022 16:23:38 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'openssl' (tried: D:/Programmes/Wamp/bin/php/php8.1.2/ext/openssl (Le module spécifié est introuvable), D:/Programmes/Wamp/bin/php/php8.1.2/ext/php_openssl.dll (La procédure spécifiée est introuvable)) in Unknown on line 0
[12-Oct-2022 16:23:38 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'curl' (tried: D:/Programmes/Wamp/bin/php/php8.1.2/ext/curl (Le module spécifié est introuvable), D:/Programmes/Wamp/bin/php/php8.1.2/ext/php_curl.dll (La procédure spécifiée est introuvable)) in Unknown on line 0
[12-Oct-2022 16:23:38 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'openssl' (tried: D:/Programmes/Wamp/bin/php/php8.1.2/ext/openssl (Le module spécifié est introuvable), D:/Programmes/Wamp/bin/php/php8.1.2/ext/php_openssl.dll (La procédure spécifiée est introuvable)) in Unknown on line 0
```

but these files DO exist at these locations.
I tried to redownload them
I also tried to download and put libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll kinda everywhere (in php bin, apache bin, php ext, SysWOW64)
Nothing works

I also have D:\Programmes\Wamp\bin\php\php8.1.2\ in my system PATH

Comment: So are you trying to use this from a web site, or from the command line?

Comment: From a website ! I need it to make a Drupal 9 website work (But even in a vanilla php website openSLL Support shows "disabled")

Comment: If your os is windows then you may try to use backslash instead of slash in your path in php.ini

Answer (score 0):

In the end I completely uninstalled WAMP (after doing a backup of my databases and moving the www\ folder out of the WAMP folder, because all of this is deleted on WAMP uninstall) and reinstalled it, and now it works like a charm.

I found no other way around it